# Can I run flask on an Apache server with mod_python?

Tags: python, apache, ftp, flask, mod-python

I have a pre-configured `Apache` server with neither `root` nor any shell access. I only can push files via `ftp`.

However, I know that the server supports Python via `mod_python`. Here is what the config says:

```
Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny16 with Suhosin-Patch mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.5.2
```

I wonder whether I can run `flask` on it. My idea would be to create a `virtualenv` locally and deploy it via `ftp`.

The big question is whether I can deploy `flask` on `mod_python` without any `mod_wsgi` which I guess is not preconfigured.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881474/deploying-a-wsgi-application-on-mod-python

Comment: Where on the machine can you write? Can you copy in Apache config files?

Answer (score 0):

I would say no. I have only seen mod_wsgi being used and the website docs themselves only talk about using mod_wsgi. You can check them out for more information http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/

You could always try out Heroku which allows you to get your flask app up and running for free, or just pay the $5 a month for the digital ocean account :).